# To solve $\frac{dx}{dt}=\tan x$ , $\frac{dy}{dt}=-\sin^2 x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The coordinates of moving point P satisfy equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\tan x,~~~~~~~~\frac{dy}{dt}=-\sin^2 x$$ for $t\geq 0$. The curve passes through the point $(\frac {\pi}{2},0)$ when $t=0$. Find the equation of the curve in rectangular coordinates.
[image]

I'm having problem with second equation. It does not involve $dx$, is there a trick to solve it?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat edited

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dt}=\tan x$ and the curve passes through $(\frac {\pi}{2},0)$?  You mean $\tan \frac {\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Could you show the result for the first equation ?

Comment: I fixed the title to agree with the equation in the body. Please check and fix if I introduced any errors.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $lnsinx=t+c$

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Am I wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Sorry ! Stupid typo's !!!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici can you undelete your answer? I actually liked it (although I forgot to upvote it, sorry!), and the flaw I pointed out is probably more of a flaw about the question itself than about your answer.

Comment: @JoeyZou. Done, I quoted your comment. Thanks.

Comment: C'mon guys i am sorry for typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\large\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=-\frac{\sin^2 x}{\tan x}=-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$$

Hence $$y=\frac{1}{4}\cos 2x + c$$

But the curve passes through $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$.

So $c=\frac{1}{4}$

Hence the required curve is $$y=\frac{1}{4}\cos 2x + \frac{1}{4}$$ or $$4y=1+\cos 2x=1+2\cos ^2 x-1=2\cos^2 x$$
$$y = \frac{1}{2}\cos^2 x$$

Comment: Seems okay, but doesn't agree with options

Comment: @SophieClad Matches with option (A). Is it okay now?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat. You solution is for sure faster than mine. $+1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The first equation being $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\tan(x)$$ you can rewrite it as $$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$ Integrating $$t+C=\log(\sin(x))\implies x=\sin^{-1}(e^{t+C})$$ Applying the condition gives $C=0$; so $x=\sin ^{-1}\left(e^t\right)$.

**As JoeyZou commented, this must be taken with care since it introduces severe constaints on $t$**.

Now, the second equation write $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\sin^2(x)=-e^{2 t}$$ which is quite easy to integrate $$y=-\frac{e^{2 t}}{2}+D$$ Applying the condition gives $D=\frac 12$.

So, to summarize $$x=\sin ^{-1}\left(e^t\right)\qquad , \qquad y=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-e^{2 t}\right)$$

I m sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Wouldn't $\frac{dy}{dt}=-e^{2t}$?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat. For sure; I use to make stupid typo's (I am almost blind and I often miss "minor" things such as a sign !!). Thanks for pointing it. Cheers.

Comment: For $t>0$, we would have that $e^t>1$, and so $\sin^{-1}(e^t)$ is not defined. But I'm not sure how to make sense of it, since in the accepted answer (which matches yours after some manipulations) we have that $y$ is nonnegative, but we also have $\frac{dy}{dt}<0$...

Comment: @JoeyZou. You are right ! I delete my answer because it includes a lot of restrictions about $t$. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So the other answers are good enough to answer your question, and in particular gives you the answer in a way that the book probably expected you to get. There's just a slight problem with the question: the trajectory you describe *cannot* exist.

By that, I mean the following claim:

**Claim**: There does not exist a real-valued function $x(t)$ (defined on some right-neighborhood of $0$) such that

- $\frac{dx}{dt} = \tan x$ for $t>0$, and
- $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0^+}{x(t)} = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

To see this, we assume that $x$ exists, and solve for $x$. We have
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \tan x\implies \cos x\frac{dx}{dt} = \sin x\implies \frac{d}{dt}(\sin x) = \sin x. $$
Hence, $\sin(x(t))$ satisfies the differential equation $\frac{df}{dt} = f$, and the solutions to this equation are of the form $f(t) = Ce^t$ for some constant $C$. So $\sin(x(t)) = Ce^t$. By continuity, we have $1 = \sin(x(0)) = Ce^0 = C$, so
$$\sin(x(t)) = e^t.$$
But $e^t>1$ for $t>0$, while $\sin$ can only take values between $-1$ and $1$, contradiction. So no such trajectory exists.

In addition, notice that the "correct answer" $y = \frac{1}{2}\cos^2 x$ implies that $y$ is always nonnegative. However, at $t=0$ we have $y= 0 $ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = -\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -1$. Since $x$ is continuous, it follows that $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is negative in some neighborhood of $t=0$, and so the trajectory, if it existed, would make $y$ negative.

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule:

$\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}=-sin^{2}(x)(\frac{1}{tanx})=-sin^{2}(x)(\frac{cosx}{sinx})=-sinxcosx=-\frac{1}{2}sin2x$

Comment: sorry there was a typo in question